# (JavaScript) Find the Area of a Circle From User Input Box

Tags: javascript, html, pi

Alright, so I am trying to figure out what I am doing wrong here and would love for someone to help me in the right direction.

I will have all the code below. As well as on CodePen if that helps [here](https://codepen.io/agtshadow/pen/poweOpd)

I am looking to make a simple HTML page, where:

1. Function finds the area of a circle
2. The formula should be π (pi) r squared, right? or is it Math.PI?
3. Use π as the constant
4. The user will enter their first name in a textbox
5. The user will enter the radius from the second textbox
6. Calculate the area of a circle.
7. Concatenate the user's first name, a message, and the area of the circle and output all of that into the document.
   Thank you so much for anyone who can help me with this, I have been stuck on this all day, and could use some help. Even if not the answer, just someone who could point me in the right direction, or what I am doing wrong? Thank you all.

```js
function changeText() {
             var firstName = document.getElementById("fNameBox").value;
             var message = ", The area of your circle \"is\"";
             const radius1 = circleRadius + " " + Math.PI;
             var result = firstName.toUpperCase() + message + radius1;
        document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = (result);
      }

      function clearText() {
        document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = "<br>";
        document.getElementById("fNameBox").value = "";
        document.getElementById("wageBox").value = "";
      }
```

```css
body {
        background-color: antiquewhite;
        font-family: "Segoe UI", Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
        text-align: center;
      }

      h1,
      h2,
      h3,
      h4,
      h5,
      h6 {
        text-decoration: underline;
      }

      span {
        margin-top: 0.5em;
        margin-bottom: 0.5em;
        font-style: italic;
      }
```

```html
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Program 4</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="main">
      <div id="header">
        <h1>Program 4</h1>
        <span>An Expression using a Constant</span>
      </div>
      <br /><br />
      <form id="myForm">
        First Name: <input type="text" id="fNameBox" /> <br /><br />
        Radius (Of Circle): <input type="text" id="circleRadius" /> <br /><br />
        <p id="demo">Output:</p>
        <p id="message"><br /></p>
        <p id="radiusOutput"><br /></p>
      </form>
      <!-- Buttons For Submit & Clear -->
      <button type="button" onClick="changeText()">Submit</button>
      <button type="button" onClick="clearText()">Clear</button>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You could get the area of a circle like so `Math.PI * circleRadius.value ** 2`.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I cannot find where to mark it as the answer sorry I am here for an issue deploying my React web app portfolio and it will not deploy or even work locally now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get the radius input value first because the `radiusOutput`  variable you were trying to use is undefined. Also, you need to use `parseInt()` to convert input value of type String to type Number.

```
const radius1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("circleRadius").value) * Math.PI;
```

Also, I recommend using `<input type="number"` for radius instead of `text`.

```js
function changeText() {
             var firstName = document.getElementById("fNameBox").value;
             var message = ", The area of your circle is: ";
             const radius1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("circleRadius").value) * Math.PI;
             var result = firstName.toUpperCase() + message + radius1;
        document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = (result);
      }

      function clearText() {
        document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = "<br>";
        document.getElementById("fNameBox").value = "";
        document.getElementById("wageBox").value = "";
      }
```

```css
body {
        background-color: antiquewhite;
        font-family: "Segoe UI", Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
        text-align: center;
      }

      h1,
      h2,
      h3,
      h4,
      h5,
      h6 {
        text-decoration: underline;
      }

      span {
        margin-top: 0.5em;
        margin-bottom: 0.5em;
        font-style: italic;
      }
```

```html
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Program 4</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="main">
      <div id="header">
        <h1>Program 4</h1>
        <span>An Expression using a Constant</span>
      </div>
      <br /><br />
      <form id="myForm">
        First Name: <input type="text" id="fNameBox" /> <br /><br />
        Radius (Of Circle): <input type="number" id="circleRadius" /> <br /><br />
        <p id="demo">Output:</p>
        <p id="message"><br /></p>
        <p id="radiusOutput"><br /></p>
      </form>
      <!-- Buttons For Submit & Clear -->
      <button type="button" onClick="changeText()">Submit</button>
      <button type="button" onClick="clearText()">Clear</button>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much! I even fixed it before this and was editing the code snippet where I was getting the radius. However, it kept saying HTML Object, etc. so forth, so I was still banging my head against the keyboard and about to start smoking cigarettes or walking around clearing my head of this simple stuff I know I know, it's been so long inside Kali Linux doing my OSCP, returning to this I got rusty, but thank you, good sir (or ma'am)!!!!! 
This is the answer. Should I close it now? Or leave it up? How can I thank you, buy you a coffee or something?

Comment: No worries, please just upvote the answer and mark it as accepted if it helped, cheers!